# How to make a block sparse matrix from n size blocks?

Tags: matlab

Is there a quick way to fill a (sparse) matrix with A and B block as such in Matlab:

```
 A, B, 0, 0, 0
 B, A, B, 0, 0
 0, B, A, B, 0
 0, 0, B, A, B
 0, 0, 0, B, A
```

I tried this code

```
e=full([A B; B A]);
e1=e;
for i=1:n
   e=blkdiag(e,e1);
end
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. What is the issue with the code you posted? Are you getting any error?

Comment: No,it works. But the problem is  that the output matrix is larger then n*n (n is the block size )

Comment: Are `A` and `B` matrices? Could you give an example for these?

Comment: I tried this exemple for n=3 : A=B=eye(3) which give me a 24*24 matrix!

Comment: I understand that `n = size(A,1)` ( = `size(B,1)`) is the block size, and both `A, B` are square.  But how many times should `A` be repeated on the (block) diagonal of the result?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do the following (save the function to a file `blktritoep.m`):

```
function C = blktritoep(A, B, nb)
% A, B must be square of and same size for this to work
% nb = number of times A gets repeated on the diagonal of C
A = sparse(A); % Does nothing if A is already sparse
B = sparse(B); % Idem
C = kron(diag(ones(nb,1)), A) + kron(diag(ones(nb-1,1), 1), B) + ...
    kron(diag(ones(nb-1,1), -1), B);
end
```

The output I get for, say,

```
A = ones(2,2);
B = -2 * ones(2,2);
C = blktritoep(A, B, 3);
full(C) % Result is sparse, just for pretty printing!
```

is

```
ans =

     1     1    -2    -2     0     0
     1     1    -2    -2     0     0
    -2    -2     1     1    -2    -2
    -2    -2     1     1    -2    -2
     0     0    -2    -2     1     1
     0     0    -2    -2     1     1
```